# SharePoint 2013 Page Layout Error

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm really finding it difficult to set up a new theme for my SharePoint 2013 site.
I have uploaded all other files to the design gallery. But when I uploaded the page layouts, and I try to change the **Content Type** to **Page Layout**, I get the error below:

> Sorry, something went wrong List does not exist.
>   The page you selected contains a list that does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.

Technical Details 
Correlation ID: ce2b429d-0147-d0c2-bc23-32b039f7d8a6

Please what can I do to resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: looking for that id in the logs might provide a bit more detail on what is happening. also, check you have a "Pages" list, otherwise it may indicate missing features to support publishing

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But where can I find the "Pages" list?

Comment: you should have a list "Pages" accessible from either site content or sharepoint designer. if not, you'll need to activate "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" under "Site settings" > "Site Collection Administration" > "Site collection features"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the browser, go to your site, and on the Site Actions menu, click
>   View All Site Content, and then click the Pages document library.
>
> Or you can browse directly to
>   http://your_site/pages/forms/allitems.aspx, where your_site is the URL
>   for your site, such as fabrikamweb/finance for the
>   http://fabrikamweb/finance subsite.
>
> The Pages document library is created automatically by the publishing
>   feature and contains all of the pages in a site that are created from
>   page layouts. You can look in the Page Layout column to see which page
>   layout was used for a specific page and then click the link to view
>   that page in the browser.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-a-publishing-page-layout-c10bda25-0145-44c6-ba14-7757176fb47f

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by disabling the publishing feature under > `site settings > Site Collections Feature > SharePoint Server Standard Site Collection features`

1. Deactivate
2. Reactivate
3. Rebooted the server (probably could have done an IISReset but
   overkill!)

Now I can add layout pages under master pages gallery.